# FriendlyID - Assigning a slug before it is saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I've an ActivityType model that creates a dynamic page after being created, with a slug equalling the ActivityType's slug.

If a page already exists with this slug, it is throwing a validation error, so I'm trying to change the slug of the ActivityType before it is saved, assuming that a Dynamic page already exists with that slug.

I've written the following code:

```
def check_and_change_slug
  n = 1
  slug = title
  while DynamicPage.exists?(slug: slug)
    slug = title + "-#{n}"
    n + 1
  end
end
```

My question is, if I perform this code before saving the record, will Friendly ID attempt to create a new slug, or simply go with the one I've manually assigned?

I've looked through the documentation and SO but can't seem to find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `candidates` functionality in order to achieve this:

```
class ActivityType < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged

  def slug_candidates
    n = 1
    slug = title
    while DynamicPage.exists?(slug: slug)
      slug = title + "-#{n}"
      n += 1
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - sorry I should have stated in my opening question - there may be a dynamic page already existing even if the slug has not been used before so I need to do a manual check and assignment - your code certainly makes sense but I don't think can be used here

Comment: @Mark I've updated my answer. You may insert your code into `slug_candidates` method. I've tested it in a sample project and it worked as expected